# How to use EF Core (EF7) with Mysql server?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am developing asp.net 5 (now called ASP.NET Core) on linux. But I cannot connect between EF7 (now called EF Core) and Mysql server. Please tell me any solution that you knew.

Thanks.

Comment: how did u realized it? any news to mysql support? :)

Comment: Yes, I did. It's a good news :)

Comment: How did u realized it? Using EF7 with MySql? Or using another Database? Or using MySql and EF6?

Comment: You may check right here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/sql-server-on-linux.aspx

Comment: @mxii For now I used MySql and EF6 on vNext.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All available providers are listed at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/. At time of writing, there are 3 different EF Core providers, two community versions and one official version.

**UPDATE Sept 15, 2016**

MySQL released the first version of an official provider for EF Core.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore

There is also a community version of a MySQL provider

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySQL

**UPDATE May 23, 2016**

MySQL has announced (quietly) that they are building an EF Core 1.0 provider. There are no details yet on its availability. See https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/providers/mysql/index.html

Also, DevArt announced a month ago that their (proprietary, not-free) providers support EF 7 on .NET Framework only, including their MySQL provider. No news yet about their intention to support .NET Core. http://blog.devart.com/entity-framework-core-1-entity-framework-7-support.html

Comment: Thanks. Did asp.net 5 have a plan support for mysql? if yes, when will it release?

Comment: Oracle offers MySQL support for EF 6. I haven't seen anything about their intentions to support EF 7.

Comment: is the answer still true?

Comment: Yes. Here are all the providers available. http://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/providers/index.html

Comment: It is not that true anymore... See here ! [link](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/providers/mysql/index.html#coming-soon)

Comment: Updated original post above with two links and current status as of 5/23/16.

Comment: Several .NET Core-compatible MySQL connectors were released recently: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39179035/2756471 (and even one EF Core provider)

Comment: https://github.com/SapientGuardian/SapientGuardian.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql is also a good MySQL provider.

Answer (score 4):

I have good news, guys. Like one said : "Pas le temps de niaiser".
Entity Framework 7 **will support soon** MySQL, trusting this page from the documentation : 
https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/providers/mysql/index.html#coming-soon

Comment: It appears that a prerelease version is now available at https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore/7.0.4-IR-191

Comment: Thus far, I'm unable to get it to restore and build on Linux: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39330191/dotnet-core-on-ubuntu-linux-using-asp-net-mvc-and-ef-mysql-error-nu1001-cannot