# .Net Core MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I've just started coding in Visual Studio Code with .NET Core, on Ubuntu 14.04.4
I'm used to both using Ubuntu (from personal interests, hobby, etc) and .NET and Visual Studio at work.

But I've run into a problem i can't seem to overcome. I'm building a small console app that i want to communicate with a MySql Server, but I can't seem to get the MySql.ConnectorNET.Data working properly.

It was installed with the command `dnu install MySql.ConnectorNET.Data` And that seemed to work fine. The dependency was added in the project.json file, and intellisense was able to traverse the package just fine, but the OmniSharp Log reports that:

```
[INFORMATION:OmniSharp.Dnx.DnxProjectSystem] Project /home/<username>/VSCode/SimpleSQLatmpt/project.json has these unresolved references: MySql.ConnectorNET.Data
```

and I simply can't seem to fix that. VSCode seems to detect it, and asks me to run the `dnu restore` command. But it's to no avail. For all intends and purposes it seems like MySql.ConnectorNET.Data is available in the project, but just can't be used.

Can any one tell me how to fix this?
And just as important, why it is happening in the first place?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Are there any warning symbols when you expand your project references?

Comment: VSCode doesn't have the classic dependencies tree in the left panel. I can open the project.json file to view all dependencies, in there it looks fine, like it references the correct package from nuget

Comment: .NET Core is special and requires a special build. Far too any components are not yet ready for this new platform, so don't play with it yet even though you can be brave.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

At the time of this question (Mar 2016) there was no .NET Core-compatible ADO.NET provider for MySQL.

Now situation is changed:

- [MySqlConnector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector) written by Bradley Grainger -- licensed under MIT, and offers full async support
- [MySql.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/7.0.7-m61) (>6.10) provided by Oracle (traditionally, GPL)

Personally I prefer MySqlConnector -- it can be used in commercial projects for free (MIT license); also I've tested it with my [NReco.Data](https://github.com/nreco/data) library under Linux, and it works perfectly in my scenarious. Unfortunately, MySqlConnector doesn't support EF Core yet.

--- UPDATE --

One more .NET Core-compatible MySQL connector + EF Core MySQL provider:

- [Pomelo.Data.MySql](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.Data.MySql) (unfortunately it doesn't implement true async behaviour)
- [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql)

Comment: `MySql.Data.Core` doesn't exist anymore. Please see https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.Core/

Comment: @MuhammadUmmar you're right MySql.Data.Core was deprecated and now net-core compatible build is available for MySql.Data package (I've updated the link).

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE 2**

MySql Connector NET for .NET Core 1.0 was just released (Sep 2016)
http://insidemysql.com/mysql-connector-net-for-net-core-1-0/

I didn't try Bradley Grainger's connector, but this one from MySQL do not support SSL. :(

So, anybody who wants to use anyway, should connect with ";SslMode=None;" in the connection string.

Comment: Well, i like using the Official connectors, but no SSL is a bit of a deal breaker.

Comment: We just added SSL support in v0.3.0 of MySqlConnector: https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/

Comment: MySql.Data from Oracle also not supporting SSL as of now :(