# How to use MySql dataaccess approch using ado.net or entity framework in .net core

Tags: mysql, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I am migrating a .net 4.5 project to .net core. In an existing project I have used an enterprise library for data access. As .net core don't have support for an enterprise library, I need data access support for a MYSQL database. Can anyone suggest or provide me solution for achieving this?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39179035/2756471) with list of .NET Core-compatible providers for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Coming Soon:

https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/providers/mysql/index.html?highlight=mysql

If you poke around the forums, there are sever projects that have been started. Personally I'd wait for the official version:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,646467,647514#msg-647514