# .Net Core 2.0 Database First Approach Scaffold-DbContext of Mysql DB

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I am developing WEB API in .Net Core 2.0 with MySQL DB. I am trying to scaffolding MySQL DB. I have follow [This link (MySQL Official Site)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core-scaffold-example.html#connector-net-entityframework-core-scaffold-packagemgr) but when I fire scaffolding command I getting error both I have mention below, please do let me know if I am doing anything wrong.
Command For Scaffolding(firing in Package Manager Console)

```
Scaffold-DbContext "server=localhost;port=3306;user=root;password=darshan7826;database=sakila" MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir sakila -f
```

Error on executing above command

```
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
at MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.MySQLDatabaseModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, IEnumerable`1 tables, IEnumerable`1 schemas)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, IEnumerable`1 tables, IEnumerable`1 schemas, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ModelScaffolder.Generate(String connectionString, IEnumerable`1 tables, IEnumerable`1 schemas, String projectPath, String outputPath, String rootNamespace, String contextName, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContext(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContextImpl(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1 tableFilters, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
The method or operation is not implemented.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After digging i found that .Net Core 2.0  Mysql Connector is not working properly 
and after some search and RnD i found [Pomelo Foundation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39179035/5286817) from Stack overflow i tried it and it works.

Answer (score 4):

Taking a look at the official sourcecode for the [MySQL Connector for .Net](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/), you can see that it's not complete yet due to this:

```
public DatabaseModel Create(string connectionString, 
    IEnumerable<string> tables, IEnumerable<string> schemas)
{
  throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

You may want to open up a bug report on the [official bug tracker](https://bugs.mysql.com/).

Alternatively, there does seem to be a much newer beta version that you could look at trying. https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore/8.0.9-dmr

Comment: Lol, `throw new NotImplementedException();` is pretty "standard" implementation.

Comment: @Ivan It's how I implement all my code too, you'd be amazed how quickly I can write it!

Comment: @DavidG thanks for answer, can you please let me know in file i have to add this block

Comment: It is still not implemented even with newest release of 8.0.10-rc which got released just 2 days ago :(

Comment: its odd how they have a release and this function is still not implemented

Answer (score 1):

You should run this (from Package-Manager-Console):

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;" 
MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir Models
```

or use:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold
```

**Note**: You should be at the project in which `MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore` NuGet package has been added.