# Asp.net core 2.0 with entity framework database first approach with MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I just have an existing database written script in MYSQL and I just want to import all the tables into my asp.net core 2.0 web application with entity framework core. Also, I want to use database first approach into my project so that all tables should add to the project with poco classes. So please help me out in this situation.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score -1):

**1. Run the following commands:**

```
 dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
 dotnet add package MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
```

**2. Add a reference to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet**

```
 <ItemGroup>
   <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

**3. Scaffold the Database**

**3.1 Install the following NuGet packages**

```
MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

**3.2 Scaffold**

```
 Scaffold-DbContext `"server=localhost;port=3306;user=root;password=mypass;database=sakila" MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir sakila -f`
```

Comment: I follow this but got below error. PM> Scaffold-DbContext "server=localhost;port=3306;user=root;password=d4Developer@123; database=sakila" MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir sakila -f
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.MySQLDatabaseModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, IEnumerable`1 tables, IEnumerable`1 schemas)

Comment: Look at this. it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47952803/net-core-2-0-database-first-approach-scaffold-dbcontext-of-mysql-db?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa