# ASP.NET Core Reverse engineer model with MySql existing database

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, scaffolding

Im try to made a ASP.NET Core project with EF Codefirst and existing MySql database 
When I try to make the Reverse engineer ( following the article: [Getting Started with EF Core on ASP.NET Core with an Existing Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db)
)

I have a error.
My MySql package is: MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 8.0.11

My Database is: TEST
MY TABLE IS

```
CREATE TABLE USER (
  ID               BIGINT(20)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  USERNAME         VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  FIRSTNAME        VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Im using the command:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "server=localhost;port=3306;user=root;password=123;database=TEST" MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir Models
```

**The error:**

```
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.MySQLDatabaseModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, IEnumerable`1 tables, IEnumerable`1 schemas)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineerScaffolder.ScaffoldModel(String connectionString, IEnumerable`1 tables, IEnumerable`1 schemas, String namespace, String language, String contextDir, String contextName, ModelReverseEngineerOptions modelOptions, ModelCodeGenerationOptions codeOptions)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContext(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContextImpl(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputDbContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1 tableFilters, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
The method or operation is not implemented.
```

Dos someone know how can I sold this ?
Is there any way to make the models if a Wizard like ASP.NET Web API in .NET Framework?

Comment: See [.Net Core 2.0 Database First Approach Scaffold-DbContext of Mysql DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47952803/net-core-2-0-database-first-approach-scaffold-dbcontext-of-mysql-db).

Answer (score 0):

Try this its work for me. This is also NET Core-compatible MySQL connector + EF Core MySQL provider:

```
Pomelo.Data.MySql      
Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql   
Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Design
```

Answer (score 0):

Scaffold-DbContext "server=localhost;user=root;password=1234;database=test1;" Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.