# dotnet core on Ubuntu Linux using asp.net MVC and EF MySQL error NU1001: cannot restore MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: mysql, linux, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ubuntu-server

I've built a simple, flat dotnet core MVC app that I'd like to see running on Linux. It uses EF to pull a few records from a mysql table and display them in a view. It all builds and runs on my host (Win10) but will not in the Ubuntu VM I've spun up to test with

After I do a "dotnet restore", I get the following error with "dotnet build" or "dotnet run":

> Project CoreCrossPlatformFlat (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) will be
>   compiled because the version or bitness of the CLI changed since the
>   last build    Compiling CoreCrossPlatformFlat for
>   .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0
>     /opt/dotnet/corecrossplatform/src/CoreCrossPlatformFlat/project.json(25,52):
>   error NU1001: The dependency MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore >=
>   7.0.4-IR-191 could not be resolved.
>
> Compilation failed.         0 Warning(s)        1 Error(s)

FYI: Here's what "dotnet --info" reports:

> .NET Command Line Tools (1.0.0-preview2-003121)
>
> Product Information:
>    Version:            1.0.0-preview2-003121
>    Commit SHA-1 hash:  1e9d529bc5
>
> Runtime Environment:
>    OS Name:     ubuntu
>    OS Version:  16.04
>    OS Platform: Linux
>    RID:         ubuntu.16.04-x64

For the VM, I followed these instructions:

https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#ubuntu

The project.json looks like so:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "MySql.Data.Core": "7.0.4-IR-191",
    "MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore": "7.0.4-IR-191"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Here's a zip of the solution if that helps:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/kilonova-public/code/CoreCrossPlatformFlat.zip

Comment: Did you already run `dotnet restore`?

Comment: @NateBarbettini - Yes...sorry I hadn't mentioned it. Error remains the same.

Comment: Maybe worth noting: Was able to use the MySql.Data.Core to write some basic ADO.NET code, which successfully ran on the Ubuntu VM. At this point I'm unsure if there's just a problem restoring the EF package or it's just not ready for Linux?

Comment: FWIW, I restored those packages fine on macOS. Do you have the latest version of the .NET CLI tooling? What does `dotnet --info` say?

Comment: @NateBarbettini - Yes, AFAIK. Added that output to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same problem today. Please try deleting all files and folders except the project.json file and all the .cs files in your project folder. Then dotnet restore and dotnet run. It works for me. : )