# How can I use MySQL in .net Core 1.1

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-code, .net-core-1.1

I want to know how to use Mysql in .NET Core 1.1 applications.

I'm developing on Ubuntu 17.04 and it does not support .NET 4.0 or higher. I like an alternative.

Comment: did you check this http://insidemysql.com/mysql-connector-net-for-net-core-1-0/

Comment: This question was already answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169619/how-to-use-ef-core-ef7-with-mysql-server

Answer (score 1):

For 1.0 it does not exist. But now there are MySql connectors for EF Core 2.0, just consult the documentation. [Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core.html)